# New App Engine SDK unable to utilize / find locally installed Python Imaging Library

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, cloud, python-imaging-library

Yesterday I updated my google cloud SDK along with the python runtime. Now an app I was able to run locally in the SDK complains about the PIL / Python Imaging Library not being available:

```
bash-3.2$ dev_appserver.py . --host=0.0.0.0
INFO     2014-05-31 17:07:52,313 devappserver2.py:706] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-05-31 17:07:52,319 api_server.py:378] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
```

Not true, however. I DO have PIL installed and it works swimmingly with jpegs, which is what I expect:

```
bash-3.2$ ipython
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 

In [1]: from PIL import Image

In [2]: my_image = Image.open('motorcycle.jpg')

In [3]: my_image.show()
```

Works just fine. FWIW, I declare my app.yaml use of PIL as such:

```
libraries:
...
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: latest
```

I've tested it, so it's not a false negative. When I try to use the GAE images module, it's blows up with the same problem. It works just fine in production. Clearly Python has what it needs to work. Why is App Engine unable to make use of it?

Comment: I have same problem, what was the solution?

Comment: Turns out my problem was that I had two pythons: one installed via brew and the other was the system python.

Comment: Ag ok, that makes sense. Does brew install PIL as well? I can't seem to get mine fixed

Comment: It may. It depends. I generally try not to use brew for anything unless I can't solve a problem any other way. Also, getting PIL to work on your local machine can be quite involved and a lot can go wrong. a complete PIL may be installed, but no graphics file codecs may exist on the machine, so PIL won't work. So the answer to this question is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having had to do with having a clash between a brew version of python installed versus the system version. Fixing my shell's path to point to the correct python installation sorted this problem, too. For GAE users: I also had to make sure my app engine SDK path was correct as well.

If you're having problems installing or getting PIL to work, understand that there are many dependencies involved with PIL, including what file format codecs you will want to support (there is a PNG library, a TIFF library and a JPEG library), and whether you want to draw text in your images and need truetype font support via the freetype library. Know that you may have PIL installed and no codec support libraries and effectively PIL won't be usable.

A good starting place for this issue might be this other question:

[How to deal with Linux/Python dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463530/how-to-deal-with-linux-python-dependencies)